# SQL server - copying tables, constraints and indexes from one database server to another server

Tags: sql-server

An accidental DBA, We have sql server 2012 on both of our payroll production server and development server. We have to copy few tables and indexes and constraints from the production database to the development database. Please let me know the best method to do so. I appreciate your response.

Comment: Can you take a backup of your production DB and restore the associated DBs to your dev environment? That would be the quick and easy way.

Comment: Our company is testing some schema changes that was done in the development and wants to test those changes using the production data and hence wants to choose those objects that got changed in the process.